# Is there any difference in performance between accessing a file through local path or to UNC shared path

Tags: windows, performance, unc

I have a few template files that are hosted in many places, the main reason is to have for each module the corresponding template locally accessible.

Later, I realise that those files were used through the UNC shared path for each box.

My question is:
Is there any performance difference between accessing local files through local path rather than to UNC path?

Comment: yes, of course when you access files through local path this will be faster and more effective rather than to UNC path. how much - already another question. but faster

Comment: Yes, I know but is a matter of how much. I did some experiments and the results are quite similars.

Comment: Maybe, this is only like that for .Net because Microsoft disambiguates at some point. Maybe this is different when tested in C, C++.

Comment: when you open local file - request is send direct to filesystem device. when you open file by unc - request is send to `\Device\Mup` which already resend it to local or remote filesystem. and than all read/write requests go not direct but again through `\Device\Mup` - what sense have this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the overhead in minimum. I ran some timing tests using the following code:

```
var localTimes = new List<long>();
var sharedTimes = new List<long>();

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    stopwatch.Start();
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    stopwatch.Stop();

    localTimes.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);

    stopwatch.Start();
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\localhost\Shared\Template.xlsx");
    stopwatch.Stop();

    sharedTimes.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
}

Console.WriteLine("Local: avg={0}, 50k={1}", TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)localTimes.Average()/50), TimeSpan.FromTicks(localTimes.Sum()));
Console.WriteLine("Shared: avg={0}, 50k={1}", TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)sharedTimes.Average()/50), TimeSpan.FromTicks(sharedTimes.Sum()));
```

and those are the results:

Local:  avg=00:00:00.0567284, 50k=00:47:16.4212917

Shared: avg=00:00:00.0568292, 50k=00:47:21.4612018

My conclusions are that it doesn't matter.